# Golf MK4 Turn signals not working

Tags: golf, turn-signal

So I was driving my car all day today and everything with the turn signals / hazards was working perfectly, then I parked it for maybe 10-15 mins and when I got in and started up the car I find that my turn signals aren't working for some reason (no flashing, ticking at all) yet my hazard lights work perfectly.

I read online that the problem could be with the hazard switch, but that seems to be working.
Could it be a fuse? Could the hazards still work if I had blown a fuse? I'm really confused to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate fuse *and* a separate relay.  You'll need to check both, and I hope the relay panel is a little easier to get to than it is on the MKIII, because that's a real treat.

Check the fuses first, but a fuse isn't a wear item.  They shouldn't blow unless something else is wrong as well.  If it is blown and it blows the replacement fuse as well, check the relay.  If the fuse is fine, also check the relay.

Comment: Fuses have been known to fracture - break due to vibration or manfacturing defects and the fine crack can be hard to see - test with a meter...

Comment: Good point @SolarMike.  If a fuse "burns" from an electrical fault, you can normally see it, but it's possible for it to crack.

Comment: Turns out the fuse had burned out, no idea why. Replaced it for now with the one from the hi-beams and so far it's been working perfectly.